# Why did the Egyptians mourn Jacob for 70 days? (Genesis 50:3)

Tags: genesis, jacob, egypt

This chapter brought up many questions for me. It reads in Genesis 50:3 NKJV, after Jacob breathed his last.:

> <sup>**3**</sup> Forty days were required for him, for such are the days required for
> those who are embalmed; **and the Egyptians mourned for him seventy
> days.**

**Why did they, and what is the significance of mourning for 70 days?**

Answer (score 4):

The scene portrayed in Genesis is one on a par with the mourning of Pharaohs:

> 1 Joseph flung himself upon his father and wept over him as he kissed
> him. 2 Then Joseph ordered the physicians in his service to embalm his
> father. When the physicians embalmed Israel, 3 they spent forty days
> at it, for that is the full period of embalming; and the Egyptians
> mourned him for seventy days.

Pharaohs too were mourned for [seventy days](https://www.q-files.com/history/ancient-egypt/funeral-of-a-pharaoh) in an elaborate ceremony. The Egyptians mourned for Jacob so intensely because he was the father of Joseph, the grand vizier who had saved them from famine. According to the medieval Jewish sage [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.50.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.50.3.2&lang2=bi):

> They wept for him during so long a period because a blessing
> had come to them on his arrival in Egypt for the famine then ceased
> and the waters of the Nile again increased.

**Conclusion**: the seventy days of mourning for Jacob meant that he was given a state funeral on a par with those of the pharaohs.

Comment: +1. I like that. Considering he was Hebrew that probably meant quite a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Ellicott offers this explanation:

> (3) Forty days.—Herodotus (ii. 86) describes the process of embalming
> as occupying seventy days, but he was speaking of what he saw at
> Thebes, whereas Memphis was the Egyptian capital in Joseph’s time; and
> the mummies of Thebes are, we are told, far more perfectly preserved
> than those of Memphis. Diodorus agrees very nearly with the periods
> mentioned here, saying (i. 91) that the embalming took somewhat more
> than thirty days, and the mourning for a king seventy-two. The usual
> period of mourning among the Israelites was thirty days (Numbers 20:29
> : Deuteronomy 34:8). Probably, therefore, the forty days spent in the
> embalming were included in the “threescore and ten days,” during which
> the Egyptians mourned for Jacob.

Matthew Poole offers a slightly different explanation:

> Threescore and ten days, i.e. thirty days, (according to the custom of
> the Hebrews, Numbers 20:29 Deu 34:8, to which doubtless the Egyptians
> in this case did accommodate themselves,) besides the forty days spent
> in embalming him, which also was a time of mourning. And thus I
> suppose the Egyptians reckoned those seventy-two days which Diodorus
> Siculus saith they spent in mourning for their deceased kings.

The pulpit commentary suggests that the 70 days = 40 + 30 days:

> Verse 3. - And forty days were fulfilled for him; for so are fulfilled
> the days of those who are embalmed: and the Egyptians mourned
> (literally, wept) for him threescore and ten days - i.e. the whole
> period of mourning, including the forty days for embalming, extended
> to seventy days, a statement which strikingly coincides with the
> assertion of Diodorus Siculus (1:72), that the embalming process
> occupied about thirty days, while the mourning continued seventy-two
> days;

Comment: +1. Makes sense. 40 days embalming + 30 days mourning = a total of 70 day mourning. Thank you for the different perspectives.